# populate datatable from ajax call

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

I am working on data tables but unable to populate data table with response. No error is shown.

**HTML :**

```
<table id="table" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#303641;">
        <tr>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>dateTimeStr</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Response from server :**

```
{"msg":null,"code":null,"status":null,"data":[{"number":"1234","dateTimeStr":null},{"number":"2345","dateTimeStr":null}],"draw":0,"limit":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0}
```

**Java script code:**

```
function display(number, startdate, enddate, response) {
    var cdrReqParams = {};
    cdrReqParams.number = number;
    cdrReqParams.fromDate = startdate;
    cdrReqParams.toDate = enddate;
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(cdrReqParams);
    API.call("summary.json", 'POST', function(data) {
        tableData = data.data;
        createTable(tableData);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }, jsonStr);
}
}

function createTable(tableData) {
    console.log(tableData);
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "pageLength": 100,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['colvis', 'print', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        searching: false,
        language: {
            buttons: {
                colvis: 'Show/Hide Columns'
            }
        },
        "aaData": tableData,
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "number"
        }, {
            "mData": "dateTimeStr"
        }]
    });
}
```

this code shows the `console.log(tableData)` values. But doesn't populate it into table. any idea, what is wrong here ?

Comment: which version of DataTables are you using? If I read the docs correctly, “aaData” is not used anymore, it's “data” now

Comment: datatable : 1.11 version

Comment: Someone please kill me. I hidden the table before ajax call and forgot to show it again. My mistake, sorry. Other than this, code is fine

Comment: alright then  you should delete this question